# Question about solvability of the minimal polynomial of the element in extended field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ have characteristic $0$, and assume we have fields $L\supset K\supset F$.

Now suppose $\alpha\in L$ be solvable by radicals over $K$, and the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ are solvable by radicals over $F$.

How to show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is solvable by radicals over $F$?

Comment: This is Exercise 5, page 220, from Cox's *Galois Theory* (first edition). Is it also a homework?